# Correlation Regression

Tags: regression, correlation, model-selection, regression-strategies

I need some help to figure which statistical analysis will be useful for me.
I have 15 variables and one dependent variable "Rate".
I need to find out which of the variables have more impact on rate

This is just a small sample of data.
[image]

Rate is continuous but all other have fixed values.
for eg: A can have value (2,4,8,12)

Theoretically, As the other variables increases, rate is decreased. 
But I need to prove it statistically, and Need to find out which variables from A,B,C,.. have more impact on rate.

I tried to do correlation analysis, but the coefficients I get are very low (for eg. -0.016)

Do I need to use regression or is there any other way I can do this?
[image]
Thanks!

Regression with one variable is like below 
[image]

Correlation coefficients:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried backward elimination with linear regression?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I tried to to create linear model for one variable at a time. I get coefficient of 0.4 and r square of 0.04. Is this good enough?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression

Basically you do linear regression with all the variables, and keep throwing out ones that don't have a statistically significant effect until you wind up with a set that are significant.

Comment: Also My data is not normally distributed, can this be a problem?

Comment: Potentially. It really depends.

Comment: Can you help me understanding this?
column A can have values from 2 4 8 12
and ideally as the A increases rate decreaes
But I dont know how to prove it.

let's say I have 2000 records
1400 with A = 12
300 A = 8
200 A = 4
100 A = 2

Similarly column B, C and so on

when I try to calculate correlation, I dont get very good values.
May be beacause of the way values are distributed.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Well, if the correlation isn't there then you're out of luck; you can't prove something if it's not true.

Comment: So the way they are distributed is not a problem?

Comment: Please upload the distribution of your data.

Comment: Unable to upload graph here, Bin Frequency 0 641
1.209188661 130
2.418377322 130
1.813782991 128
0.60459433 106
3.022971652 97
10.27810362 28
9.068914956 20
24.18377322 4
16.92864125 3
19.34701857 3
21.76539589 3
24.78836755 3
29.62512219 3
37.48484848 3
21.16080156 2
22.97458456 2
23.57917889 2
74.96969697 1
103.9902248 1
154.7761486 1
More 1
18.74242424 0
27.20674487 0
30.22971652 0
32.04349951 0
32.64809384 0

Comment: You can edit your question to include it.

Comment: I uploaded histogram, regression with one variable and correlation values.

Comment: Since your predictors are factors (i.e. they take on a value within a discrete set of values) you'll need to turn them into dummy variables before regressing.

You might also want to transform your data since it's all positive.

Comment: Okay. what do you mean by turning into dummy variable? and also how to transform the data? Sorry for so many question. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: These questions you can google.